# Will my dlcs be saved on a different user

Tags: ps3

Anyway so I deleted my psn account and my user because it was my sisters email and I forgot the password , I had dlcs on the user like batman arkham origins and black ops , I made a new user and psn account when I went on black ops my dlcs where not there and my batman arkham origins ones are not there either is there anyway of getting them back and getting them onto my current user .

Answer (score 2):

DLCs are owned by the buying user, but most of the DLC bought by one user can be used by other users on the same console as long as that console is activated for the owning user.

I don't think it's possible to "delete" a PSN account, what I believe you did is just delete the console **profile** associated with that user. If that's the case, what you need to do is create a new profile on your machine and log in with your other user on that profile. Go to the PSN store and download all your DLC again & install them. Go back to your new profile & log in to your new account again, and the DLC should be available in your games. Just make sure you don't delete your profile again or else you won't be able to access your DLC.

There's now way to move ownership of purchased content between accounts, and this won't seem to change in the near future.

Comment: But I don't want to even see my other psn account because it is useless and I want my dlcs to be owned by my current psn account

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to transfer content ownership between accounts. Your only option is to re-buy your DLC on our new account